# PCA working so good when I compress array from 20000 to 100

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pca

I have an array of sizes (100, 200) and their value ranges from (-2.5,2.5) of each pixel, and I have 1000 such images. I want to compress the image to 100 pixels from 200000(100, 200), so I'm using PCA for it. Here's my code:

```
pca = PCA(100)

lower_dimensional_data = pca.fit_transform(a) #a is my data

approximation = pca.inverse_transform(lower_dimensional_data)
```

It's working well when I invert it and get back the original image. Am I doing something wrong here? I'm surprised as it's inverting back so well, which means there's so much information even in 100 size array.

Can someone tell me If I'm doing something wrong or understanding something wrong?

Sample image:

[image]

Comment: The code seems correct. Can you post an example image? Otherwise, you could try to compute the mean squared error between `a` and `approximation` to see how much information you loose.

Comment: @tilman151 please check the updates ques. Yes I checked RMSE and that's also pretty low!

Comment: Seems to me that your image is "relatively simple" so it seems reasonable that a PCA with 100 components is working pretty well. If you get an RMSE that is higher than noise, the images seem different, too. Keep in mind that the importance of PCA components decreases pretty rapidly, so the first 10 might encode most of the information. In terms of possible errors? Did you flatten your image first? Otherwise PCA might interpret it as 100 sampels of size 200.

Comment: @tilman151 yup I did flatten image, shape of a is (1000, 20000).

Comment: Ok, so don't sue me if I'm wrong but it seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing nothing wrong and a lot of things right. Your images are not complex in the theoretical sense. I can see from the example image that the pixel values do not oscillate drastically. Kolmogorov complexity can be more easily explained with strings.

Your image is more like "AAAaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBbbbbbbbbbb" which though long is easy to compress (3As10as4Bs etc)

compared to say "AzF34dsvWrr" which is much shorter but more complex.